# Advice about a composite book or series on mathematics

Tags: book-recommendation, advice, learning

My question is mainly about a good book or maybe a series of books which provide me a very a basic understanding of topic of mathematics on an University level. To be specific, is there any series for mathematics like there is the Berkeley Physics Course, which dives deep into Mechanics, Electromagnetism, Waves, Quantum Mechanics and Statistical Mechanics from a very beginner's level to provide good overview and understanding about what the subject is about. I know I should not confuse Physics with Mathematics but is there some series which teaches you concepts fundamental to Mathematics but from basic level like Number Theory, Linear Algebra, Multivariable and Vector Calculus, Topology, Analytical Geometry etc. and maybe a few other stuffs like Graph Theory. I also, do not want to know books about the topics I just mentioned, but a series which may have even more than these topics or maybe if a few are missing, I will read other books specifically for that topic.

Precisely the mathematical counterpart of Berkeley Physics Course.

Comment: you could try the very encompassing book "The Princeton Companion to Mathematics" edited by Timothy Gowers, written for undergraduate and graduate students in mathematics as well as for researchers.

Comment: @DrJay Thanks for your suggestion, but I actually want a series kinda thing which will teach me things into a deep details and not the philosophy behind the subject and problem solving tactics. Thank You

Comment: For mathematical analysis, there's the Princeton Lectures in Analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_Lectures_in_Analysis). I can't think of any similar series in other topics, though.

Comment: @PeteKlimek, thanks for the suggestion!